# Add unit from other project in project group

Tags: delphi

Hi i am trying to get a simple multi project setup running in RAD studio. I trying to use DunitX to test a simple class. But i cannot figure out how to be able to add the unit i want to test in my uses clause. So how can i add my units in my uses clause in the unit test project`?

[image]

Edit:

After the replies i went and just right clicked the test project and pressed the Add button. Then i added the .pas file as a reference file to the other project. But that still seems wrong since the project CalcMan.Core is a package project so i thought i should be able to have the package as a decency or something and then i would be able to use what ever classes i wanted to test but ok this also works.

[image] [image]

Comment: Just drag and drop the unit into the target project.

Comment: You might be interested in the plugin TestInsight by Stefan Gliencke!

Answer (score 0):

There is a wizard for DUnitX test cases within menu File>new>other>DUnitX>DUnitX Unit

Comment: Yes i know that. That is how i added the DunitX project in the first place. The problem is that i cannot see the unit that i want to test when i try to add it in the uses clause.